# Azure DevOps Extension Retrieve User Time Zone

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Is there a way to retrieve the user's time zone set value for the profile thru the API?
[image: Azure DevOps Profile Time Zone]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that it is currently not supported to retrieve user's time zone through api . There is no out-of-the-box api to get user’s time zone.
You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) , which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1086895/get-the-users-time-zone-set-value-for-the-profile.html) for you. You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.